# Check and verifiy number of nodes in Hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, task, nodes, jobs

How can I know after the job has completed, how many nodes that actually ran on that job, how many map task, and how many reduce task?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You could use jobtracker UI for the same. It's running on 50030 by default and URL would look like `http://myhost:50030/.`

Once you go there, you could see how many mapper's and how many reducers that were used by your job. You could play around by clicking on job link itself.

Comment: Thanks bro for ur answer...
Actually I'm little bit confuse, several source that use jobtracker but I also read and in my hadoop that's use YARN, so the jobtracker become ResourceManager here...

is that true bro?
Thanks.....

Comment: Yes it is. Gen 1 had Jobtracker which is now in Gen 2 being handled by YARN.

Comment: thanks bro for helpful answer, 
by the way, can I ask any question about YARN if you don't mind.

Here's the problem :
I have <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
</property>

on my mapred-site.xml, that setting make my job run slower, but if I remove that property my job run faster. Do you know why that's happend? Thanks once again.....

Comment: that's bro
when I add <property> <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> <value>yarn</value> </property> on my mapred-site.xml, that setting make my job run slower, but if I remove that property my job run faster. Do you know why that's happend?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That means if you remove that property, meaning by default you are running it in local mode and hence that means no IO involved with other nodes and hence its fast. See [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) which says default value is local.

Comment: if it helped then you could accept it, so it could help others in future.